# Is there a way to receive broadcast each time any activity is launched?

Tags: java, android

for android developers

my goal is to saved when any activity is launched...

For instant is there is three activity launched during the last hour, I want to save it into a database.

Of course I could launch a service and check every seconds what activity is launched but it would use phone battery!

thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe implement an Application class, similar to a Singleton method. Then store the data within the application every time you call your new Activity.

Application : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html

Comment: I means that I want to save all activity launched, which are made by any applications, not only my application.
still thanks

Comment: Figured I'd give it a shot, what do you mean that Activities are made by Applications though? Maybe you misunderstand me, or I misunderstand you? Are you familiar with the Singleton method? You can use your application class to store data which can be used by all Activities. This way, every time you call "startActivity().." or whatever it is that you use, you can make a call to your Application saying "myApplication.addActivityLaunched( activityName )", or something along those lines

Comment: sorry my english is not perfect, I have some difficulties to translate. Maybe it's clearer like that: I want to know each time any activity of any application is launched by any application.

Answer (score 0):

finilly I believe it's not possible:

there is all broadcast actions in the file:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-15\data\broadcast_actions.txt

and no one seems to be related to any activity launch.